# Twilio Conference callback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am not able to get status callback from conference

I use:

1. PHP as backend Client
2. TwilioJs as frontend for my softphone.

Call flow looks as follows:

Inbound Call -> IVR -> enqueue Worker (Conference) -> Connect task to relative worker using JS SDK (client:support)

Usually i add statusCallback parameter to $dial->conference class but unfortunately I can't apply same method to this specific use case since conference is auto generated from enqueue class and enqueue doesn't have any callbacks.

what can be done to retrieve conference SID?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to search for it using:

[Read the conferences named `MyRoom` that are in progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-resource?code-sample=code-read-the-conferences-named-myroom-that-are-in-progress)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you're saying that you connect your worker to the call using the JS SDK and the [`reservation.conference` function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#reservation-conference).

If that is the case, then you can set a status callback URL in that function. The final argument to `reservation.conference` is an object of options and you can include the property `ConferenceStatusCallback`, like this:

```js
var options = {
    "ConferenceStatusCallback": "https://requestb.in/wzfljiwz"
}

reservation.conference(null, null, null, null, null, options);
```

That will send conference events to the URL you provide.